# How to show only one specific user and not all in Firebase?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I'm building a chat app using React Native and Firebase, All code is fine, but I want to show only one user in the list.

How to show only one specific user and not all?

For example:

- Peter
- John
- Michael
- Antony
- Administrator

I want show Administrator, not all users.

```
state = {
users:[] }



componentWillMount(){
let dbRef = firebase.database().ref('users');
dbRef.on('child_added', (val) => {
  let person = val.val();
  person.phone = val.key;
  if(person.phone===User.phone){
    User.name = person.name
  } else {
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      return {
        users: [...prevState.users, person]
      }
    })

  }
}) }

renderRow = ({item}) => {
return (
  <TouchableOpacity 
    onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Chat', item)}
    style={{padding:10, fontSize: 16, color:'#00F0C8', borderBottomColor: '#ccc', borderBottomWidth:1}}>
    <Text style={{fontSize:20}}>{item.name}</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
)  }

render(){
return(
  <SafeAreaView>
  <Text>These are the Users list</Text>
    <Card style={styles.maincard}>
      <FlatList
        data={this.state.users}
        renderItem={this.renderRow}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.phone}
        />
    </Card>

  </SafeAreaView>
)}
```

Comment: dbRef.LimitToLast(1).on('child_added', (val) =>

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can try to filter the list,

```
render(){
return(
 <SafeAreaView>
 <Text>These are the Users list</Text>
<Card style={styles.maincard}>
  <FlatList
    data={this.state.users.filter(elem => elem.name === "Administrator")}
    renderItem={this.renderRow}
    keyExtractor={(item) => item.phone}
    />
</Card></SafeAreaView>)}
```

Comment: Thank you so much David, have a nice day!